# Click through NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an `NSView` containing multiple subviews. One of those subviews is transparent and layered on top.

I need to be able to click through this view down to the subviews below (so that the view below gets first responder status), but all the mouse events get stuck on the top view (alpha is `1`, because I draw stuff in it - so it should only click through transparent areas).

I actually expected this to work, since normally it does. What's wrong?

Comment: The views `-isOpaque` is `NO`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's another approach.  It doesn't require creating a new window object and is simpler (and probably a bit more efficient) than the findNextSiblingBelowEventLocation: method above.

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    // pass-through events that don't hit one of the visible subviews
    for (NSView *subView in [self subviews]) {
        if (![subView isHidden] && [subView hitTest:aPoint])
            return subView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I circumvented the issue with this code snippet.

```
- (NSView *)findNextSiblingBelowEventLocation:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  // Translate the event location to view coordinates
  NSPoint location = [theEvent locationInWindow];
  NSPoint convertedLocation = [self convertPointFromBase:location];

  // Find next view below self
  NSArray *siblings = [[self superview] subviews];
  NSView *viewBelow = nil;
  for (NSView *view in siblings) {
    if (view != self) {
      NSView *hitView = [view hitTest:convertedLocation];
      if (hitView != nil) {
        viewBelow = hitView;
      }
    }
  }
  return viewBelow;
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
  NSView *viewBelow = [self findNextSiblingBelowEventLocation:theEvent];
  if (viewBelow) {
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:viewBelow];
  }
  [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **Swift 5** version of [figelwump's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545561/3939277):

```swift
public override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    // pass-through events that don't hit one of the visible subviews
    return subviews.first { subview in
        !subview.isHidden && nil != subview.hitTest(point)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **Swift 5** version of [Erik Aigner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390920/3939277):

```
public override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Translate the event location to view coordinates
    let convertedLocation = self.convertFromBacking(event.locationInWindow)

    if let viewBelow = self
        .superview?
        .subviews // Find next view below self
        .lazy
        .compactMap({ $0.hitTest(convertedLocation) })
        .first
    {
        self.window?.makeFirstResponder(viewBelow)
    }

    super.mouseDown(with: event)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your transparent view in a child window of its own.

Comment: Because resolving hits through transparent portions of windows is intrinsic to the window manager.  The work you did above isn't necessary.

Comment: Oh I just realized there is actually a method `-addChildWindow:` that does synchronization of the windows! Sorry, I thought I would have to do the synchronization manually then.

Comment: I tried to use this approach but it has more drawbacks that using the `-findNextSiblingBelowEventLocation:` workaround, because the window is not really tied to the `NSView` and therefore it is also drawn when the view is invisible, and does not work when the view is e.g. inside a scroll view.

Comment: This is a very heavy-handed approach to a trivial problem