# NSImageView on top prevent NSDataPicker from getting focus

Tags: swift, macos, nsimageview

MacOs app allow user to manage content on the iOs application, so I am trying to allow user to edit content in "natural invironment".

So I have a scrollview with elements and I have a NSImageView with iPhone frame on top of it(transparent in the middle). 
Everything works perfect with all NSTextField, but I have a problem with NSDataPickers. I can't get them in focus, as I presume NSImageView don't send it to them. The only way to get focus to them is to choose NSTextField before NSDataPicker and then use Tab on keyboard. Not particularly convinient.

How it is possible to sort out this problem?

[image]

Comment: `NSTextField` makes itself first responder in `mouseDown:`. `NSDatePicker` doesn't. I don't know about `NSDataPicker`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click through NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357447/click-through-nsview)